# How to use/install pip

Tags: python, pip

Noob question here on Python using pip. I've installed pip using setuptools on a Win7 32-bit machine. I am not using virtualenv.

Now trying to install enum34 for use with dbf; I need enum34 as I have to work in Python 2.7 for use with ArcGIS 10.2. In PowerShell, I get the following returned no matter what command I try to use with pip, including the command 'list'. I've also tried with the Windows basic Command Prompt and got the same results.

Did pip not install correctly? Is there some other error?

Please let me know if I've included enough information.

```
PS C:\python27\arcgis10.2\scripts> .\pip install enum34
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\python27\arcgis10.2\scripts\pip-script.PY", line 9, in <module>
  1oad_entry_point('pip==l.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()

 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point

 Fi1e "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2363: in load_entry_point

 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
  )

 File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  from pip.util import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
```

....etc.

Comment: As the message says the most recent problem is last so please post the whole message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My goto solution for python libraries on windows is

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

They have prebuilt binary installers for tons of projects. enum34 is available.

Comment: This seemed to work. I will test out enum34 and see if it's installed correctly. Thanks! I still want to get pip installed correctly so I am going to continue to comment on the other answers.

Comment: No problem. If I were you I'd install virtualenv from the site above. Nowadays I do almost all of my python work in virtualenvs. Once I got the hang of it (took almost no time at all) it's just so easy. One of the biggest benefits is you never have to worry about permissions, and you know everything lives in the virtualenv directory.

Answer (score 2):

[Download `get-pip.py` and run it as Administrator.](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) Pip should then be on your path, so you can just use `pip install enum34` instead of `.\pip install enum34`. If that doesn't work, tell us the error message you get.

Comment: Getting an error message when running get-pip.py. Unfortunately I can't post a screenshot of the error so I will do my best to type it in.

File "get-pip.py", line 17474, in <module> main()
File "get-pip.py", line 17466, in main bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
File "get-pip.py", line 17406, in bootstrap import pip
File "longpath\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
 etc.
File "c:\Python27\ArcGis10.2\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
 return _compile(pattern, flags)
File "c:\Python27\ArcGis10.2\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
 raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Comment: Seemed to have installed pip but getting an error when using it to install enum34. It looks much like the error I was getting when I ran get-pip.py. It ends with the messages:  File "c:\Python27\ArcGis10.2\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile<cr>return _compile(pattern, flags)<cr>File "c:\Python27\ArcGis10.2\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile<cr>raise error, v # invalid expression<cr>sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Comment: That's a Python bug. The regular expression was probably using "*", and Python was trying to repeat a null value. There's something wrong with your Regex file in Python (looks like it's corrupted). Can you reinstall Python?